# SwiftData, Redundant ModelContainer Instances Causing Data Constraint Loss?

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I recently encountered an issue with SwiftData where I unintentionally created multiple `ModelContainer` instances, leading to unexpected behavior. Specifically, after creating redundant `ModelContainer` instances, the constraints on Model data seemed to be lost, allowing the insertion of duplicate Item instances.

However, upon restarting the entire application, it appears that only a single Item instance remains, suggesting that the duplicated insertions were merely transient. Could this behavior be indicative of a bug within SwiftData?

I'm seeking clarification on whether this issue stems from a misconfiguration on my end or if it indeed reflects a potential bug within SwiftData. Any insights or guidance on resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```swift
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@Model
class Item {
  @Attribute(.unique)
  var name: String
  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

@MainActor
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var modelContainer: ModelContainer? = nil
  @State var items: [Item] = []
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      List {
        ForEach(items) { item in
          Text(item.name)
        }
      }
      Spacer()

      Button("AddItemInCurrentContext") {
        addItemInCurrentContext(modelContainer: modelContainer!)
        items = fetchItems(modelContainer: modelContainer!)
      }
      Button("AddItemInNewContext") {
        addItemInNewContext()
        items = fetchItems(modelContainer: modelContainer!)
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
      modelContainer = createModelContainer() // create the 1st ModelContainer instance
    }
  }
}

func createModelContainer() -> ModelContainer {
  do {
    let config = ModelConfiguration()
    return try ModelContainer(for: Item.self, configurations: config)
  } catch {
    fatalError("Could not initialize ModelContainer")
  }
}

@MainActor
func fetchItems(modelContainer: ModelContainer) -> [Item] {
  let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Item>()
  do {
    return try modelContainer.mainContext.fetch(descriptor)
  } catch {
    return []
  }
}

@MainActor
func addItemInCurrentContext(modelContainer: ModelContainer) {
  let item = Item(name: "Item") // identical name
  modelContainer.mainContext.insert(item)
  do {
    try modelContainer.mainContext.save()
  } catch {
    print("addItemInCurrentContext error: \(error)")
  }
}

@MainActor
func addItemInNewContext() {
  let item = Item(name: "Item") // identical name
  let newModelContainer = createModelContainer()
  newModelContainer.mainContext.insert(item)
  do {
    try newModelContainer.mainContext.save()
  } catch {
    print("addItemInCurrentContext error: \(error)")
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}
```

[Snapshot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BizyQFZY27c)

Comment: Why would you want a ModelContainer to be a `@State` property and why would you want to have multiple instances here? While the documentation says that an app "must have _at least one_" container it also recommends that you use the `.modelContainer` modifier so that the container is shared for all your views. Don't make things more complicated than they are, use `.modelContainer(for: Item.self)` on your `WindowGroup` instead.

Comment: I'm encountering a challenge with accessing a ModelContainer from a View that I'm importing directly into an AppIntent. The View is not within a WindowGroup, and consequently, I'm unable to gain access to the necessary ModelContainer instance.

Comment: To resolve this, I modified the code to save the ModelContainer instance as a global variable, which effectively fix the problem.

However, I'm curious about whether this approach aligns with common practices or if there are alternative, more recommended solutions for scenarios like this, particularly within the context of an AppIntent.

Comment: I haven't worked with AppIntent yet but this might very well be a case where having a second ModelContainer is valid. But even so it should only be one instance in this scope so however AppIntent works I gather it should be a single `let` declared instance available through the whole scope.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. The fundamental guideline to adhere to is the utilization of only a single instance of the ModelContainer class. I have implemented this requirement through the use of a static property. (I am unsure about your reference to a 'let' declared instance.) Nevertheless, I appreciate your advice.